# How to get general ItemContainer type for WPF ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I want to determine `ItemContainer` type from an existing `ItemsControl` object.

```
   var item = control as ItemsControl;
    //HOW to get child container Type?
```

An example of how it's done by a Blend:

[image]

Blend somehow determines that the current `TabControl` type child item is `TabItem`.

How to do the same thing in code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [`StyleTypedPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.styletypedpropertyattribute.aspx) on most classes derived from `ItemsControl`. Get the one having `Property` equals to `"ItemContainerStyle"`. The `StyleTargetType` property on this attribute should give you the item type.

Note that you have to be careful not to get attribute from the base class. Also, while this works for most types (`TabControl`, `ListBox`), some classes such as `DataGrid` are simply not annotated with this attribute.

Here is the list I use for built-in framework types:

```
var _itemsContainerTypeByContainerType = new Dictionary<Type, Type> {
    { typeof(ComboBox), typeof(ComboBoxItem) },
    { typeof(ContextMenu), typeof(MenuItem) },
    { typeof(DataGrid), typeof(DataGridRow) },
    { typeof(DataGridCellsPresenter), typeof(DataGridCell) },
    { typeof(DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter), typeof(DataGridColumnHeader) },
    { typeof(HeaderedItemsControl), typeof(ContentPresenter) },
    { typeof(ItemsControl), typeof(ContentPresenter) },
    { typeof(ListBox), typeof(ListBoxItem) },
    { typeof(ListView), typeof(ListViewItem) },
    { typeof(Menu), typeof(MenuItem) },
    { typeof(MenuBase), typeof(MenuItem) },
    { typeof(MenuItem), typeof(MenuItem) },
    { typeof(MultiSelector), typeof(ContentPresenter) },
    { typeof(Selector), typeof(ContentPresenter) },
    { typeof(StatusBar), typeof(StatusBarItem) },
    { typeof(TabControl), typeof(TabItem) },
    { typeof(TreeView), typeof(TreeViewItem) },
    { typeof(TreeViewItem), typeof(TreeViewItem) }
};
```