# Is there a way of using virtualization with hidden panels or expanders?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, virtualization

I'm trying to improve performance with my WPF application and I'm having problems with a complex ItemsControl. Although I've added Virtualization, there's still a performance problem and I think I've worked out why.

Each item contains a series of expandable areas. So the user sees a summary at the start but can drill down by expanding to see more information. Here's how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, there's some nested ItemsControls. So each of the top level items has a bunch of Hidden controls. The virtualization prevents off-screen items from loading, but not the hidden items within the items themselves. As a result, the relatively simple initial layout takes a significant time. Flicking around some of these views, 87% of time is spent parsing and Layout, and it takes a few seconds to load.

I'd much rather have it take 200ms to expand when (if!) the user decides to, rather than 2s to load the page as a whole.

Asking for advice really. I can't think of a nice way of adding the controls using MVVM however. Is there any expander, or visibility based virtualization supported in WPF or would I be creating my own implementation?

The 87% figure comes from the diagnostics:

[image]

Comment: What is *"hidden items within the items themselves"* ? Virtualization will not create [`ContentPresenter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12437064/1997232), but somewhere you have `ObservableCollection<>` which has to be fully loaded. So, what is this `2s` includes? Have you done profiling to see what actually is a bottleneck?

Comment: Do you want to virtualize part of item which is inside `Expander` (for created items)? If yes, then you can handle collapsed state in ViewModel to **add more data** when it's expanded (e.g. using `object` to hold that data and data-template to create some visual when it's not `null`).

Comment: That is how it does the layout.  You could delay getting the data until it is open.  I am surprised that takes 2 seconds.

Comment: @ContentPresenter, hidden items = Visibility.Collapsed, set to Visible when shown.

That's a very good idea, I can just set the observable collections when the visibility state has been changed, that would be super easy. I'll see how it manages.

Comment: Hmm, I removed the expanders completely and I'm facing similar load times. I've added an edit

Comment: @Sinatr Good idea, will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply have

```
- Expander
      Container
          some bindings
    - Expander
          Container
              some bindings
+ Expander
+ Expander
... invisible items
```

Then yes, `Container` and all bindings are initialized at the moment when view is displayed (and `ItemsControl` creates `ContentPresenter` for visible items).

If you want to virtualize content of `Expander` when it's collapsed, then you can use data-templating

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items = ... // bind ItemsControl.ItemsSource to this

class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool _isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded // bind Expander.IsExpanded to this
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            Data = value ? new SubItem(this) : null;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Data));
        }
    }

    public object Data {get; private set;} // bind item Content to this
}

public SubItem: INotifyPropertyChanged { ... }
```

I hope there is no need to explain how to to do data-templating of `SubItem` in xaml.

If you do that then initially `Data == null` and nothing except `Expander` is loaded. As soon as it's expanded (by user or programmatically) view will create visuals.

Comment: Using templates is a great idea, I've implemented it pretty much how you describe and the performance is much improved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd put the details of the solution, which is pretty much a direct implementation of Sinatr's answer.

I used a content control, with a very simple data template selector. The template selector simply checks if the content item is null, and chooses between two data templates:

```
public class VirtualizationNullTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NullTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NullTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return Template;

        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that the ContentControl I used still lays out the data template even if the content is null. So I set these two templates in the xaml:

```
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding VirtualizedViewModel}"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ><!--Visibility="{Binding Expanded}"-->
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
                        <StackPanel>
                            ...complex layout that isn't often seen...
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="NullTemplate"/>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
                    <Helpers:VirtualizationNullTemplateSelector Template="{StaticResource Template}" NullTemplate="{StaticResource NullTemplate}"/>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
            </ContentControl>
```

Finally, rather than using a whole new class for a sub-item, it's pretty simple to create a "VirtualizedViewModel" object in your view model that references "this":

```
    private bool expanded;
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return expanded; }
        set
        {
            if (expanded != value)
            {
                expanded = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => VirtualizedViewModel);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Expanded);
            }
        }
    }


    public MyViewModel VirtualizedViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (Expanded)
            {
                return this;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've reduced the 2-3s loading time by about by about 75% and it seems much more reasonable now.

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution helped me:

```
<Expander x:Name="exp1">
   <Expander.Header>
     ...
   </Expander.Header>
   <StackPanel
      Margin="10,0,0,0"
      Visibility="{Binding ElementName=exp1, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <Expander x:Name="exp2">
        <Expander.Header>
          ...
        </Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel
          Margin="10,0,0,0"
          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=exp2, Path=IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

Comment: This solution is very simple and fast, it seems that making expander's content visibility binded to it's expand property will hugely affect the rendering. The only problem is that collapsing the items is no longer animated but instant

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to achieve this is to change the default Visibility of the contents to Collapsed. In this case WPF won't create it initially, but only when a Trigger sets it to Visible:

```xml
<Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
  <Setter Property="Visibility"Value="Visible" TargetName="ExpandSite"/>
</Trigger>
```

Here "ExpandSite" is the ContentPresenter within the default ControlTemplate of the Expander  control.
Note that this has been fixed in .NET - see the default style from the WPF sources on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/c271205b80c27df976acbd7236ec637090d127c1/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/Themes/XAML/Expander.xaml).

In case you have an older version, you can still use this fixed control template to update the old one with an implicit style.

You can apply the same technique to any other panel or control.

It's easy to check if the control was already created with [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf). Once you attached it to your application, you can filter the visual tree with the textbox on the top left. If you don't find one control in the tree, it means it was not created yet.

Comment: I've tried following this and can't make it work, I think a more complete example would help. "TargetName" is not allowed on Style triggers, members of the Triggers collection must be EventTriggers which do not have a "Property". Two of the errors I got.

Comment: Take a look at the linked sources from github. You can see that the TargetName="ExpandSite" is used inside ControlTemplate.Triggers.

The easiest way to achieve the lazy loading is to update to a newer .NET Framework version.

If that is not an option, you could use a tool like WPF Style Snooper to get the default Expander style from your .NET version, extend it with this trigger and override the default style with your modified style in your application.